# Setting up hardware for playing live electronic music

Tags: electronic-music

I hope that I'm here at the right place, i want to upgrade my dj setup, creating a live looping with different effects instead of playing
only with cdjs, can anyone give me some hardware suggestion which can make on setup more fun and creative.
right now i have pioneer  cdj and Allen & Heath xone 92
thank you!

Comment: Welcome. When you read the help centre, you will realise why this sort of question gets closed. Sorry!